# Return object tags as a list

Tags: django, tagging, django-taggit

Using django-tagging, for an object that has multiple tags assigned to it, how can I return a simple list of tag names?

object.tags() returns an object that is not easily translated to json, and TaggableManager is not iterable.

Any other ways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a undocumented function in TaggableManager called 'get_query_set', from which it is easy to get the list:

```
tagsList = []
for tag in foobar.tags.get_query_set():
  tagsList.append(tag.name)
```

Answer (score 3):

First variant

```
class MyClass(models.Model)
    ...
    def get_tag_names(self):
        return [tag.name for tag in Tag.objects.get_for_object(self)]
```

Second variant:

```
class MyClass(models.Model)
    ...
    def get_tag_names(self):
        return Tag.objects.get_for_object(self).values_list('name', flat=True)
```

I think both should work.

Comment: That _should_ have worked - but for some reason I had trouble referencing and importing Tag.

Comment: what do you mean "had trouble referencing"?

Comment: As is, the code would not reference Tag. I tried 'import Tag' and 'from taggit import Tag' but that did not work either.

Comment: from taggit.models import Tad

Answer (score 0):

```
tags_list = []
for tag in foobar.tags.all():
  tags_list.append(tag.name)
```